# Need SQL query to export students attendance report by classes

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables:

- students table

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Jhon |
| 2 | Emma |
| 3 | Oliver |

- classes table

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Math |
| 2 | Science |

- attendance table

| id | student_id | class_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |

I tried to write an SQL query to retrieve the students who attended both math and science classes:

```
SELECT s.id, s.name
FROM attendance a
INNER JOIN students s ON a.student_id = s.id
WHERE a.class_id IN (1,2);
```

the above code result is

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Jhon |
| 2 | Emma |
| 1 | Jhon |

But Emma only attended Math class.

I know this behavior is because of `WHERE IN`, it's the same as `WHERE a.class_id = 1 OR a.class_id = 2`.


But what should I do to get the expected results, Which is "Jhon" or only Jhon's ID because he is the only one who attended Math and Science Classes?

Comment: I suggest using aggregation:  `COUNT`, `GROUP BY`, and `HAVING` in addition to what you already have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either join to attendance twice, once for each class:

```
SELECT s.id, s.name
FROM students s 
JOIN attendance a1 ON a1.student_id = s.id and a1.class_id = 1
JOIN attendance a2 ON a2.student_id = s.id and a2.class_id = 2
```

or join to both classes at once and use group by with having:

```
SELECT s.id, s.name
FROM students s 
JOIN attendance a ON a.student_id = s.id and class_id in (1, 2)
GROUP BY s.id, s.name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a CTE would help, and can help you extend to multiple classes. You are also missing a `DISTINCT` keyword, which is why Jhon appears twice. Maybe something like this:

```
WITH attendance_count(student_id, classes_attended)
AS (
 SELECT
    student_id,
    COUNT(id) AS classes_attended

    FROM attendance a 

    -- change this to change the classes
    WHERE a.class_id IN (1,2)

    GROUP BY student_id
)

SELECT DISTINCT s.id, s.name
    FROM attendance_count 
    INNER JOIN students s ON attendance_count.student_id = s.id

    -- if different number of classes, change this
    WHERE classes_attended = 2
```